# Why do tangent curves have the same derivative?

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have two level sets and I choose two curves, one from each set. Let's suppose these two curves touch at a point. Why will their derivatives be the same?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 1):

Here's an intuitive picture: Recall the interpretation of the tangent at a point $p$ on a curve as the direction in which you move on changing $p$ slightly.

If the tangent to curve $A$ at $p$ intersects curve $B$, and curves $A$ and $B$ coincide at $p$, that means that $A$ must move into $B$ and cut it at two distinct points: $p$ and something close to $p$, and the two can't 'touch' at $p$, only intersect. So their tangents coincide at $p$. The derivative is simply the slope of the tangent, and must also be identical.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of a single variable function $f(x)$ evaluated at some point $x=a$ *is* the slope of **the** tangent line at that point.

$$m_{tangent} = f'(a)$$

Note the emphasis on **the** tangent line. There's only one such line. So if two curves are tangent to one another at $x=a$, then they share that same tangent line. Thus they have the same derivative at that point.

We can generalize this to any set of level curves.